# A terrible man stalks the coast, what is he?

Tags: riddle

Wrapped in Scorn and emo-black,
he towers with his massive hat.
His voice a roar, his fingers knives,
few who he touches e'er survive.
When seen approaching all birds scatter,
and grass he breathes on becomes flatter.

**What is he?**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling - this is a nice riddle! (I've slightly changed the formatting - hope you don't mind.)

Comment: Just FYI, the contraction of ever is "e'er".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a

> Tornado

Wrapped in Scorn

> No one wants to see one, except for morbid curiousity

and emo-black, he towers with his massive hat.

> dark and threatening, towering over the landscape, wider at the top

His voice a roar, his fingers knives, few who he touches e're survive.

> slicing through everything it touches

When seen approaching all birds scatter,

> everyone runs away

and grass he breathes on becomes flatter.

> the wind flattens everything around.

Comment: The "massive hat" in your interpretation could also be the storm system it's in.

Comment: I like your interpretation of the "wrapped in scorn line."

Answer (score 16):

Is it a:

> Lawnmower

His voice a roar

> The engine is quite loud

Fingers are knives

> The blades underneath the lawnmower

Few who he touches e'er survive

> Nothing that get hit by the blades really stays the same

Grass he breathes on becomes flatter

> The lawnmower mows the grass

Not sure about the part with emo-black

Comment: My gasoline-powered mower went about in quite a persistent cloud of emo-black until I put new rings in.

Comment: Scorn/emo also applies to the fact that teenagers are often the ones doing the lawnmowing.

Comment: If the blade was dull it would flatten the grass rather than cut it

Comment: @Robert Tester That is true, but I was thinking in the sense of the knives, and the general conception is that knives are sharp

Answer (score 16):

Could it be:

> A thunderstorm?

Wrapped in Scorn and emo-black,
he towers with his massive hat.

> Towering cumulonimbus clouds

His voice a roar, his fingers knives,
few who he touches e're survive.

> Lighting strikes or microbursts (or both).

When seen approaching all birds scatter,
and grass he breathes on becomes flatter.

> Birds leave ahead of a storm, the wind flattens the grass, a microburst would **really** flatten the grass.

Comment: I'm wondering about the "terrible man" part.

Comment: All the bug tropical storms that ravage coast lines are named after people since the late 19th century, the title was far more of an after thought though

Comment: @RobertTester Nice.

Comment: According to wikipedia only 10 to 30% of lightning strikes are fatal, so the "few who he touches e're survive" isn't strictly correct.

Comment: @RobertTester - Yes, but half the storms have women's names, so it only sort of works.  I suppose you could be referring to one specific storm that happens to have a male name, but that would only work if there was an active tropical storm when you presented this puzzle.  (There may be one, but I don't feel like checking - we are a little out of season right now...)

Comment: I suppose the "touch" could be from the microbursts that are often associated with thunderstorms. A sailing ship (for example the *Pride of Baltimore*) or a landing airplane caught in a microburst can be in a world of trouble.

Comment: Any thoughts on the "wrapped in scorn" part?